# VPN configuration added in to device & in device it is showing connected but not reflecting in to Open VPN Server

Tags: ios, swift, server, openvpn

I have integrated the OpenVPN XOR library for connecting OpenVPN(https://github.com/FuturraGroup/OpenVPNXor)

I'm able to add the configuration file in to device and able to connect the VPN on iPhone
device (iOS 16.2 version) but it is not reflecting any history in Open VPN server and after approximate in 1 minute it gets disconnected automatically.Please refer the screenshot attached.
Strange thing is that it does not reflect on any history on Server i.e. no logs history for connection or disconnection or user name on server.

[VPN Configuration and connection status](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UovYT.jpg)

Could you please help me in understanding what is the issue. I'll be really grateful to you.

**below is the code of the implementation.**

final class VPNManager {

```
let vpnManager = NEVPNManager.shared()
func initVPNTunnelProviderManager() {
    self.vpnManager.loadFromPreferences { (error) -> Void in
        self.checkVPNConfiguration()
        if((error) != nil) {
            print("VPN Preferences error: 1")
        } else {
            let IKEv2Protocol = NEVPNProtocolIKEv2()
            IKEv2Protocol.username = "myusername"
            IKEv2Protocol.serverAddress = "144.202.9.42" //server tunneling Address
            IKEv2Protocol.remoteIdentifier = "securevpn.com.myserver" //Remote id
            IKEv2Protocol.localIdentifier = nil //Local id
            
            IKEv2Protocol.deadPeerDetectionRate = .low
            IKEv2Protocol.authenticationMethod = .none
            IKEv2Protocol.useExtendedAuthentication = true //if you are using sharedSecret method then make it false
            IKEv2Protocol.disconnectOnSleep = false
            
            //Set IKE SA (Security Association) Params...
            IKEv2Protocol.ikeSecurityAssociationParameters.encryptionAlgorithm = .algorithmAES256
            IKEv2Protocol.ikeSecurityAssociationParameters.integrityAlgorithm = .SHA256
            IKEv2Protocol.ikeSecurityAssociationParameters.diffieHellmanGroup = .group14
            IKEv2Protocol.ikeSecurityAssociationParameters.lifetimeMinutes = 1440
            //IKEv2Protocol.ikeSecurityAssociationParameters.isProxy() = false
            
            //Set CHILD SA (Security Association) Params...
            IKEv2Protocol.childSecurityAssociationParameters.encryptionAlgorithm = .algorithmAES256
            IKEv2Protocol.childSecurityAssociationParameters.integrityAlgorithm = .SHA256
            IKEv2Protocol.childSecurityAssociationParameters.diffieHellmanGroup = .group14
            IKEv2Protocol.childSecurityAssociationParameters.lifetimeMinutes = 1440
            
            let kcs = KeychainService()
            //Save password in keychain...
            kcs.save(key: "VPN_PASSWORD", value: "hSyeI1H8Wsybb5qDk5abBrJ7LCu3bPbJrax9aFG77FiiJZu3eUepLwvg9pjjEL3")
            //Load password from keychain...
            IKEv2Protocol.passwordReference = kcs.load(key: "VPN_PASSWORD")
            self.vpnManager.protocolConfiguration = IKEv2Protocol
            self.vpnManager.localizedDescription = "Quilr VPN Configuration"
            self.vpnManager.isEnabled = true
            
            self.vpnManager.isOnDemandEnabled = true
            //print(IKEv2Protocol)
            
            //Set rules
            var rules = [NEOnDemandRule]()
            let rule = NEOnDemandRuleConnect()
            rule.interfaceTypeMatch = .any
            rules.append(rule)
            
            print("SAVE TO PREFERENCES...")
            
            //SAVE TO PREFERENCES...
            self.vpnManager.saveToPreferences(completionHandler: { (error) -> Void in
                if((error) != nil) {
                    
                    print("VPN Preferences error: 2")
                } else {
                    
                    print("CALL LOAD TO PREFERENCES AGAIN...")
                    //CALL LOAD TO PREFERENCES AGAIN...
                    self.vpnManager.loadFromPreferences(completionHandler: { (error) in
                        if ((error) != nil) {
                            print("VPN Preferences error: 2")
                        } else {
                            var startError: NSError?
                            do {
                                //START THE CONNECTION...
                                try self.vpnManager.connection.startVPNTunnel()
                            } catch let error as NSError {
                                startError = error
                                print(startError.debugDescription)
                            } catch {
                                print("Fatal Error")
                                fatalError()
                            }
                            if ((startError) != nil) {
                                print("VPN Preferences error: 3")
                                //Show alert here
                                print("title: Oops.., message: Something went wrong while connecting to the VPN. Please try again.")
                                print(startError.debugDescription)
                            } else {
                                //self.VPNStatusDidChange(nil)
                                print("Starting VPN...")
                                //START THE CONNECTION...
                                self.vpnConnectionStatusChanged()
                            }
                        }
                    })
                }
            })
        }
    }
}

func checkVPNConfiguration() {
    let isVPNInstalled = vpnManager.isOnDemandEnabled || vpnManager.isEnabled || (vpnManager.protocolConfiguration != nil)

    if isVPNInstalled {
        print("VPN configuration is installed on the device.")
    } else {
        print("VPN configuration is not installed on the device.")
    }
}

//MARK:- Connect VPN
static func connectVPN() {
    VPNManager().initVPNTunnelProviderManager()
}

//MARK:- Disconnect VPN
static func disconnectVPN() {
    VPNManager().vpnManager.connection.stopVPNTunnel()
}


func vpnConnectionStatusChanged() {

    let status = self.vpnManager.connection.status
     print("VPN connection status = \(status)")

     switch status {
         
     case NEVPNStatus.connected:
           print("connected")

     case NEVPNStatus.invalid, NEVPNStatus.disconnected :
         print("disconnected")

     case NEVPNStatus.connecting , NEVPNStatus.reasserting:
         print("connecting")

     case NEVPNStatus.disconnecting:
         print("disconnecting")

     default:
         print("Unknown VPN connection status")
     }
 }
```

}